# How can I share config in a multiprocessing environment?

Tags: python

The output will be 0 for both runs of runMP despite changing the config.x in Main. What I want is 0 and then 1.

Without multiprocessing, I get 0 and 1.

Reason I assume is the 'forked' all have individual copies of the config and overwriting it doesn't work! Not sure.

How can I solve this issue (I really don't want to pass config objects all down the chain from Main to other functions)?

```
#config.py
x = 0

# Main.py
import multiprocessing as mp
import config

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runMP()
    config.x = 1
    runMP()


# MP.py
import Main

def runMP():
# create pool, run async etc
# ....
    print Main.config.x
```

Comment: Why don't you want to pass config objects to main? Using globals is (generally) a bad programming practice, and using a config object instead might solve exactly this problem.

Comment: Put the config in a `dict` or `Namespace` proxy object and use a [`multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager) to share its current contents among the processes.

Comment: Passing down through main would end up being a lot of changes...hoping for something easier. But it is looking more likely the way to go, as the issue is I run the code with and without "mulitprocessing" turned on and off....so not sure sync manager will work.

Comment: This page has some info [https://kaushikghose.wordpress.com/2016/08/26/python-global-state-multiprocessing-and-other-ways-to-hang-yourself/] (multiprocessing and globals) However, I still dont get why if under __Main__, I change a config and it isnt passed to the other running python instances...

Comment: It's not changed in other processes because each one gets a _copy_ of it — using a `SyncManager` and passing a `dict` proxy to each of the sub-processes will keep changes made to it concurrently synchronized.